# Different formatting of footnote mark in text and in footnote

Tags: footnotes

I want that my footnotes have numbers like this:

- in the text : like this : `(7)` instead of just `7`.
- in the bottom of the page (where the note text is) : like this :    `7. This is my note... blah...`

If I use :

```
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
```

then there is parantheses (...)  in the text, but also in the bottom : `(7). This is my note... blah...`, and I don't want this.

Any idea?

Comment: I would use the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package with the `footref` macro, but there's got to be a way of redefining it, which is what you're asking for.  In a pinch, though...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's quite easy with `scrextend`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\ }
\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{(\thefootnotemark)}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textheight}{10cm} % just for the example

\begin{document}
A footnote.\footnote{\lipsum[1]\lipsum*[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: The explanation can be found in KOMA-Script documentation, since `scrextend` is made to provide a lot of KOMA-Script specific stuff to users of other document classes.

Answer (score 7):

You want `\thefootnote` not to have the brackets

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote})
```

then define

```
\makeatletter

\def\@footnotemark{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
  \hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont(\@thefnmark)}}%
  \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
  \relax}

\makeatother
```

To put the brackets back in the mark.

Answer (score 6):

Does the following produce the desired result?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefnmark{%
    \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont (\@thefnmark) }}
}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em%
    {\hss \hbox {\normalfont \@thefnmark.} }#1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
My footnote\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for this answer for illustrating what I was missing while trying to answer.