# Advanced footnote layout with word definition

Tags: footnotes

I am struggling since a few days on a special requirement asked by an author.

Suppose you have a text in which you have foot notes, and you want to define the meaning of words. For example in french "amour" can either be "love" or "like". Therefore the author would like to have in the text "amour1" when it is "love" and "amour2" when it is "like" and display the definition after the footnote.

For a better understanding I have done "by hand" and example to show you what he wants.

First the footnotes and after the definition of words in alphabetic order of appearance.

---

[image]

---

or even better should be to have the definition of the words on the right (2 columns ?) like that

---

[image]

---

I have looked in the standard footnotes, in bigfoot, in footmise and in multifoot, but I do not find a way to match the requirement.

---

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I validated the solution of @Steven B. Segletes as it was the closest to what I asked and greatly help me in pointing out the path to follow. I updated/modified the solution he gave, adding the `perpage` and including `manyfoot` to have something with two separated footnote streams.

Now I need to find out how to put the second footnote stream on the right and I asked a new question for that : [Laying out two footnote streams one beside the other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192475/laying-out-two-footnote-streams-one-beside-the-other)

The solution I ended up with is the following :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{scrextend, perpage}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}


\def\resetfootnotemarks{%
  \deffootnote[1em]{0em}{1em}{$^{\alph{footnote}}$}%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\alph{footnote}}}%
}
\resetfootnotemarks

\newcommand\footdef[3]{%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
  \setcounter{footnoteA}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnoteA}{-1}%  
  \setbox0=\hbox{#2$^{\thefootnotemark}$:\ }%
  \deffootnote[\wd0]{0em}{1em}{#2$^{\thefootnotemark}$:\ }%
  #2\footnoteA{#3}%  
  \resetfootnotemarks%
}

\newcommand\footdefmark[2]{%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
  #2\footnotemark[#1]%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\alph{footnote}}}%
}

\textheight5in
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{this is a standard footnote} and 
another\footnote{Another footnote} of normal footnotes.
Now we wish to test the use of footnote definitions.
This is a \footdef{1}{test}{noun meaning of test} 
of the Emergency broadcast system in which ``test'' is used as a noun.
But we can also \footdef{2}{test}{verb meaning of test} the verb meaning
of the word.  I can repeat a \footdefmark{1}{test} of something already done.
I can choose a new \footdef{4}{word}{a sequence of letters with meaning}
and differentiate it from a \footdef{3}{word}{a grouping of $n$ bytes
forming the bit width of the processor} for the Z80 processor.
And this is back to\footnote{A Normal Footnote} a normal footnote.
This is a test\footnote{this is a standard footnote} and 
another\footnote{Another footnote} of normal footnotes.
Now we wish to test the use of footnote definitions.
This is a \footdefmark{1}{test}{noun meaning of test} 
of the Emergency broadcast system in which ``test'' is used as a noun.
But we can also \footdefmark{2}{test}{verb meaning of test} the verb meaning
of the word.  I can repeat a \footdefmark{1}{test} of something already done.
I can choose a new \footdefmark{4}{word}{a sequence of letters with meaning}
and differentiate it from a \footdefmark{3}{word}{a grouping of $n$ bytes
forming the bit width of the processor} for the Z80 processor.
And this is back to\footnote{A Normal Footnote} a normal footnote.
\end{document}
```

And the result is :

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this? If not, I'd try to find a solution.

Comment: One question right away: is it necessary to sort the footnotes into two groups or wouldn't it be better to have them in the order of usage in the main text? I have no idea how to sort footnotes...

Comment: @KeksDose in the pictures I give, the second one with the word definition on the right is the solution the author would like to have. For the sorting, if possible he would prefer, however if it's not possible he would like at least the word definition on the right. Note that for me, in terms of layout, it should look like a footnote, but if it's a textbox (i don't know the exact word for that) or any other solution that look as what i show in picture 2 is ok for me.

Comment: @KeksDose you probably already understood, but I would like to point out that if a word definition is found many times in the same page, it should only appear one time on the bottom right and not appear many times.

Comment: OK, so far, so difficult. I'm on a short trip for the next days, so I won't be able to come up with something right now... My general idea is to put the when, where etc. into the margin with a different counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the `scrextend` package which I first read about here: [Different formatting of footnote mark in text and in footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111490/different-formatting-of-footnote-mark-in-text-and-in-footnote).  It mimics features of KOMA-Script for other document classes, so to read up on the documentation, one looks for KOMA-Script, for example, here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf.

The syntax I introduce is

`\footdef{number}{word}{definition}`

to introduce a new `definition` of `word` using the definition `number`.  If I am citing a definition previously provided, I use

`\footdefmark{number}{word}`.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend, lipsum}
\newcounter{svfn}
\def\resetfootnotemarks{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\thesvfn}%
  \deffootnote[1em]{0em}{1em}{$^{\alph{footnote}}$}%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\alph{footnote}}}%
}
\resetfootnotemarks
\newcommand\footdef[3]{%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
  \setcounter{svfn}{\thefootnote}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#2$^{\thefootnotemark}$:\ }%
  \deffootnote[\wd0]{0em}{1em}{#2$^{\thefootnotemark}$:\ }%
  #2\footnote{#3}%
  \resetfootnotemarks%
}
\newcommand\footdefmark[2]{%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
  #2\footnotemark[#1]%
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\alph{footnote}}}%
}
\textheight2.5in
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{this is a standard footnote} and 
another\footnote{Another footnote} of normal footnotes.

Now we wish to test the use of footnote definitions.
This is a \footdef{1}{test}{noun meaning of test} 
of the Emergency broadcast system in which ``test'' is used as a noun.
But we can also \footdef{2}{test}{verb meaning of test} the verb meaning
of the word.  I can repeat a \footdefmark{1}{test} of something already done.
I can choose a new \footdef{1}{word}{a sequence of letters with meaning}
and differentiate it from a \footdef{2}{word}{a grouping of $n$ bytes
forming the bit width of the processor} for the Z80 processor.

And this is back to\footnote{A Normal Footnote} a normal footnote.
\par\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am having an issue with this, that my first footnote gets indented by a space. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean footnote "a" or footnote "1", based on my MWE?

Comment: Thanks for that! But I tried to understand the code, and luckily fixed it. Thanks again for this help!

Comment: But I am still confused. Could you please explain what purpose each line serves?

Answer (score 2):

You have asked for footnotes. I find it confusing to have two kinds of footnotes and suggest to put the definitions into the margin. So the definitions don't interfere with footnotes.

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn, scrlayer-scrpage, calc, perpage,
  xspace}


 \DeclareNewNoteColumn[font=\sffamily\footnotesize, width=3cm, 
 position=\oddsidemargin+1in+\textwidth-3cm+\marginparsep]{randnot}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% Counterreset every new page
% with package perpage, there also is zref-perpage
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}% print letters as anchors
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{Rnnr}%
\textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}% Anker im Text
  \makenote[randnot]{% Randnotiz
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}#1\xspace}} %%Randnotentext


\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}[0cm]{3cm}

  Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
  When\Anm{when\textsuperscript{1}: first meaning of when}\label{rn:first-when} you click
  Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want
  to add. You can also type a keyword to search on line for the video
  that best fits your document. To make your document look
  professionally produced, Word provides\footnote{This is a standalone
    footnote} header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that
  complement each other.

  For example, you can add a matching\footnote{Footnote next} cover
  page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements
  you want from the different galleries. Themes and styles also help
  keep your document coordinated. When\Anm{when\textsuperscript{3}: third meaning of
    when}\label{rn:third-when} you click Design and choose a new
  Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match
  your new theme.

  When\textsuperscript{\ref{rn:first-when}} you apply styles, your
  headings change to match the new theme. Save time in Word with new
  buttons that show up where\Anm{where\textsuperscript{2}: second meaning of
    where}\label{rn:second-where} you need them. To change the way a
  picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout
  options appears next to it. When\Anm{when\textsuperscript{2}: Second meaning of
    when}\label{rn:second-when} you work on a table, click
  where\textsuperscript{\ref{rn:second-where}} you want to add a row
  or a column, and then click the plus sign.  Reading is easier, too,
  in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts ofthe document and
  focus on the text you want.  If you need to stop reading before you
  reach the end, Word remembers
  where\textsuperscript{\ref{rn:second-where}} you left off - even on
  another device. Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your
  point\footnote{Last footnote}.


\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

This is just a demonstration, not a full blown solution.

[image: pagedesign]

Comment: @HpTerm Regarding your last comment: this is something I already considered, have a look into the code: Everywhere I use `\ref`I refer to an already given definition!

Comment: I am sorry I missed that point. I'll show the author your proposition as well and check with him if this is satisfying.