# Parallel footnote and sidenote environments with nested references

Tags: footnotes, tufte, sidenotes

I am having trouble getting an parallel footnote and sidenote environment with nested references to work. 
`fnpct` is used to create multiple footnote environments and kerning. The `bigfoot` package allows to create two named enviromenents (one for URL, the other for side notes). Within the sidenotes, there are additional references to URL's printed as regular footnotes. 
Currently, the issue is that, when I redefine the `footnoteSide`, nested footnotes are no longer printed.

Please consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[]{bigfoot}
    \usepackage[punct-after=true,multiple=true]{fnpct} 
    \DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{URL}[alph]
    \usepackage{alphalph}
    \renewcommand{\thefootnoteURL}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteURL}}}
    \DeclareNewFootnote{Side}[arabic]
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\fnurl}[1]{\footnoteURL{\url{#1}}}

    \renewcommand{\footnoteSide}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{footnoteSide}%
    \Footnotemark\thefootnoteSide%
    \marginpar{\Footnotemark\thefootnoteSide\raggedright#1}}

    \begin{document}

    \addchap{Seerechtsübereinkommen}

    Das Seerechtsübereinkommen der Vereinten Nationen (SRÜ; englisch United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea, UNCLOS) ist ein internationales Abkommen des Seevölkerrechts, das alle Nutzungsarten der Meere regeln soll. Die UN-Seerechtskonferenz dauerte von 1973 bis 1982 und war die dritte ihrer Art. Die Konferenzen zuvor werden als 'UNCLOS I' und 'UNCLOS II' bezeichnet.\footnoteURL{\url{http://www.admiraltylawguide.com/conven/unclostable.html}}\footnoteURL{\url{http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:21998A0623(01)&rid=2}}

    Das Übereinkommen fasst das vorher geltende, in den Genfer Seerechtskonventionen kodifizierte Seerecht zusammen, legt die vorher umstrittene Breite des Küstenmeeres und seiner Anschlusszone fest und entwickelt die Regelungen zum Festlandsockel fort.\footnoteSide{Mit dem Übereinkommen wurden mehrere internationale Institutionen geschaffen\footnoteURL{\url{https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Internationaler_Seegerichtshof}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

The closest example I have found in the forum is [showing how to use these parallel environments, but the nested footnotes do not work this way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192475/laying-out-two-footnote-streams-one-beside-the-other)

Also, using the `sidenote` package with `fpnct` seems to be currently broken.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you split the `\footnotemarkURL` from the `\footnotetextURL` you can escape this problem. Not that elegant, but it does work:

```
 \documentclass[]{scrbook}

 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage[]{bigfoot}
 \usepackage[punct-after=true,multiple=true]{fnpct} 
 \DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{URL}[alph]
 \usepackage{alphalph}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnoteURL}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteURL}}}
 \DeclareNewFootnote{Side}[arabic]
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\fnurl}[1]{\footnoteURL{\url{#1}}}

 \renewcommand{\footnoteSide}[1]{%
 \stepcounter{footnoteSide}%
 \Footnotemark\thefootnoteSide%
 \marginpar{\Footnotemark\thefootnoteSide\raggedright#1}}

 \begin{document}

 \addchap{Seerechtsübereinkommen}

 Das Seerechtsübereinkommen der Vereinten Nationen (SRÜ; englisch
 United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea, UNCLOS) ist ein
 internationales Abkommen des Seevölkerrechts, das alle
 Nutzungsarten der Meere regeln soll. Die UN-Seerechtskonferenz
 dauerte von 1973 bis 1982 und war die dritte ihrer Art. Die
 Konferenzen zuvor werden als 'UNCLOS I' und 'UNCLOS II'
 bezeichnet.\footnoteURL{\url{http://www.admiraltylawguide.com/conven/unclostable.html}}\footnoteURL{\url{http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:21998A0623(01)&rid=2}}

 Das Übereinkommen fasst das vorher geltende, in den Genfer
 Seerechtskonventionen kodifizierte Seerecht zusammen, legt die
 vorher umstrittene Breite des Küstenmeeres und seiner
 Anschlusszone fest und entwickelt die Regelungen zum
 Festlandsockel fort.\footnoteSide{Mit dem Übereinkommen wurden
   mehrere internationale Institutionen
   geschaffen\footnotemarkURL}

 \footnotetextURL{\url{https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Internationaler_Seegerichtshof}}

 \end{document}
```